# Detect whether charset exists in ruby

Tags: ruby, character-encoding

Is it possible to check in Ruby whether a given charset exists/is installed.

For example:

`check('utf-8')` -> True.

`check('utf-88')` -> False.

Comment: Is this what are you looking for `Encoding.find('utf-8')` or `Encoding.list` ? Though find will raise error if does not exists

Comment: Can you clarify your question? UTF-8 is not a character set, it is a character encoding. Also, what does it mean for a character set to "exist"?

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag One part of my app converts strings from one encoding like ISO-8859-1 to another like UTF-8. But in some cases the user provides wrong encoding name like ISO-9959-1 or ISO-8000. In these cases I got an error "Invalid Encoding". Instead I looked for a method which could specifically throw error like "unknown encoding name"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved with [`Encoding.find`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Encoding.html#method-c-find). However, this raises an argument exception if the encoding does not exist:

```
Encoding.find('utf-8') # => #<Encoding:UTF-8>
Encoding.find('utf-88') # => ArgumentError: unknown encoding name - utf-88
```

A simple workaround would be to rescue the exception:

```
Encoding.find('utf-8') rescue nil # => #<Encoding:UTF-8>
Encoding.find('utf-88') rescue nil # => nil
```

Alternatively, if you'd rather not deal with exceptions, you could use [`Encoding.name_list`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Encoding.html#method-c-name_list):

```
Encoding.name_list.include?('UTF-8') => true
Encoding.name_list.include?('UTF-88') => false
```

However, this approach also has a downside, in that the the queried encoding is now case sensitive - for example:

```
Encoding.name_list.include?('utf-8') => false
```

If this is problematic, you could use a case insensitive comparison such as:

```
Encoding.name_list.any?{ |encoding| encoding.casecmp('utf-8').zero? }
```